# leaflet javascript for loop through geojson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a url containing simple point feature geojson that I am displaying in my web map.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "WORK", "pk": "3"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.66645479202272, 40.79366860930495]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "Great Swamp", "pk": "5"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.47975158691408, 40.71239442660529]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "stupid abid", "pk": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.25096586314858, 40.64616085364607]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "Rutland", "pk": "2"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-72.97393798828126, 43.61022814178643]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "Sota", "pk": "4"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-94.52636718750001, 46.46813299215556]}}]}
```

in js

I simply use

```
var incidences = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/incidence_data/")
incidences.addTo(map);
```

and it correctly gets added.

I know there is a onEachFeature option which would essentially act as a for loop going through each feature but I want to know how to use a for loop to on the incidences variable and print out each name

```
for (var x in incidences.features)
    console.log(incidences.features[x].properties.name);
```

nothing shows up

---

console.log(incidences)

```
e {urls: Array(1), ajaxParams: {…}, _layers: {…}, options: {…}, _events: {…}, …}
ajaxParams
:
{dataType: "json", callbackParam: "callback", local: false, middleware: ƒ}
options
:
{}
urls
:
["http://127.0.0.1:8000/incidence_data/"]
_events
:
{data:loaded: Array(1), data:progress: Array(1)}
_firingCount
:
0
_initHooksCalled
:
true
_layers
:
{1334: e, 1336: e, 1337: e, 1338: e, 1339: e}
_leaflet_id
:
1335
__proto__
:
e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know how to use a for loop to on the incidences variable

You can't.

In your code, `incidences` is an instance of `L.GeoJSON.AJAX`. Because of class inheritance, it's also an instance of [`L.GeoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#geojson), [`L.FeatureGroup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#featuregroup), and [`L.LayerGroup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#layergroup).

None of those classes implement the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), therefore it's not possible to use a [`for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). And if you try to use a [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), that will iterate through the instance's *methods and properties*, not through the GeoJSON features.

The canonical way in Leaflet to do what you want to do is to use the [`getLayers()` method of `L.LayerGroup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#layergroup-getlayers) (which, because of class inheritance, is also available in `L.FeatureGroup`, `L.GeoJSON` and `L.GeoJSON.AJAX`), store the resulting [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) somewhere, and iterate through that:

```
var incidenceGroup = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/incidence_data/")

/* ...wait for it to load with whatever method... */

var incidenceLayers = incidenceGroup.getLayers(); // incidenceLayers will be an Array

for (var incidence of incidenceLayers) { /* do stuff */ }

// Or also a more classical for(;;) loop:
for (var i, l=incidenceLayers.length; i<l; i++) { 
   var incidence = incidenceLayers[i];
   /* do stuff */ 
}
```